# how to pass parameters in redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Starting with Ruby on rails, I've generated a ProvsController using scaffold.

It generated me this create method:

```
def create
  @prov = Prov.new(prov_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @prov.save
     format.html {redirect_to @prov, notice: 'Success'}
     format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @prov}
  else
     format.html {render :new}
     format.json {render json: @prov.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
  end
end
```

and

```
private
def prov_params
  params.require(:prov).permit(:name, :description)
end
```

I want to send parameters back to the view under some conditions, that is to say if `params[:location].nil?` is not true. I did this:

```
format.html {redirect_to params[:location].nil? ? @prov : provs_url(location: 1), notice: 'Success.'}
```

But `@prov` and `provs_url` are not the same. I tried

```
@prov : @prov(location: 1)
@prov : prov_url(location: 1)
```

and some other variations, unsuccessfully. All those combinations throw errors.

What I want is to send the `location` param back to the same view as in `@prov`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I was testing over test and I found this solution

```
format.html {redirect_to params[:location].nil? ? @prov : provs_path(id: @prov.id, location: 1), notice: 'Success.'}
```

and it worked for me.